# ng-repeat got more and more element when used in ng-transclude and toggled by ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

Here is my full test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController',['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.model = {
                    showList: false,
                    list:[1,2,3,4]
                }
            }]).directive('withTransclude', function(){
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    transclude: true,
                    template:'<div><span>transclude container</span><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
                    link:function($scope, $element, attr, ctrl, transclude){
                        // i dont want the ng-transclude tag so i replaced it
                        // if comment this expression problem disappear but the ng-transclude tag remains
                        $element.find('ng-transclude').replaceWith(transclude());
                    }
                }
            })
        </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="MainController">
      <button ng-click='model.showList = !model.showList'>toggle show</button>
      <div ng-if="model.showList">
          <span>shown</span>
          <with-transclude>
              <div>hello</div>
              <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="number in model.list">{{number}}</li>
              </ul>
          </with-transclude>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Problem:
When using ng-transclude, I don't want the ng-transclude tag remains in my page, so i replaced it with the transcluded content,but when toggle ng-if by clicking button, more and more ng-repeat element got rendered, if I don't replace,it's ok.

Question:
Why this problem occurred? and is there any other way to remove the ng-transclude tag, which doesn't give this problem.

Comment: and code in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mNw2GcSfnFFMxi6wCfQB?p=preview

Comment: your saying that 1,2,3,4 are repeating on clicking on toogle right??

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$element.find('ng-transclude').replaceWith(transclude());
```

To:

```
var transcludeEl = $element.find('ng-transclude')
$element.append(transcludeEl.contents())
transcludeEl.remove();
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/7zw27ldkGp0zeey5z9QI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try with ng-show instead of ng-if.....i didn't see the repetition when using ng-show

```
<div ng-show="model.showList">
```

[CHECK](http://plnkr.co/edit/aT9MNG6W0st4FQ6Towt6?p=preview) it